# What is meant by vector space over an algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quaternions

In Brian Hall's Book "*Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and Representations*" I find the following construction.

Let $J \colon \mathbb{C}^{2n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ be a map defined as

$$J(\alpha,\beta) = (-\beta^*, \alpha^*)$$

where $(\alpha,\beta) \in \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ and $^*$ stands for complex conjugation. Observe that $J$ is not linear but is conjugate-linear.

Define moreover the operators $i \colon \mathbb{C}^{2n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ (scalar multiplication by the complex number i) and $K = iJ$.

By putting

$$\mathbf{i} = i \quad \mathbf{j} = J \quad \mathbf{k} = K$$

and noting that these operators, together with the identity $I_{\mathbb{C}^{2n}}$, obey the quaternion multiplication rules, we have realized the quaternion algebra. In the book is stated that

$$\mbox{"We can therefore make $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ into a vector space over the noncommutative algebra $\mathbb{H}$"}$$

- What does this mean exactly? I understand the construction, but would
  rather say that the quaternions have been represented over a certain
  set of operators acting on $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$.

Comment: The quaternion algebra $\mathbb{H}$ is a division ring (i.e. noncommutative field). I think the author considers a module to be a vector space if scalar multiplication is taken over a division ring, not necessarily commutative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the definition of $I$, $J$ and $K$ give a representation of $\mathbb{H}$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$. This makes $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ into an $\mathbb{H}$-module. Thus, $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ can be considered as a quaternionic vector space, the word vector space is used because $\mathbb{H}$ is a division ring.

Comment: Perfect, I was missing the notion of module over a ring.